# npm start suddenly would not start a create-reat-app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a React app created via `create-react-app`. It was working an hour ago. Now when I run `npm start`, I got this in the Bash:

```
$ npm start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.13.4
npm info using node@v12.14.1
npm timing npm Completed in 43ms
npm info ok
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.13.4
npm info using node@v12.14.1
npm info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prestart: frontend@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: frontend@0.1.0

> frontend@0.1.0 start C:\project1\frontend
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.41.6.155/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\project1\frontend\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Compiled with warnings.

src\components\Banner.js
  Line 7:12:  'regNumber' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

I used to see bash output of app hosted on `10.41.133.24/3000`, now it doesn't work. Going to `http://10.41.6.155/` shows `This site can't be reached`, `localhost:3000` also does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: There is a linting error `regNumber' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`. Also it suggests that this is only a warning, and your server started just fine.

Comment: @Evert yeah this is only a warning, should not affect starting right? Any idea what URL my app is started at?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out why: the linting error. I thought it was just a warning and shouldn't affect starting the server, but I was wrong. After making sure there is no error in bash output, I got this:

```
$ npm start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.13.4
npm info using node@v12.14.1
npm timing npm Completed in 41ms
npm info ok
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.13.4
npm info using node@v12.14.1
npm info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prestart: frontend@0.1.0
npm info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~start: frontend@0.1.0

> frontend@0.1.0 start C:\project1\frontend
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://10.41.6.155/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\project1\frontend\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Compiled successfully!

You can now view frontend in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  http://10.41.6.155:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

And the app runs at http://10.41.6.155:3000